# XSL Dynamic convert attributes to tags and num element to make unique

Tags: xml, xslt

This XSL template convert dynamic all attributes in XML file to tags.

```
<script type="text/xsl" id="myXsltTemplate">
  <!-- Your XSLT template code goes here -->
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Your XSLT template code goes here -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
</script>
```

But sometimes xml file can have multiple times the same tag name like:

```
<image> </image> <image></image>
```

1. Which function I should add to this xsl template do dynamic convert duplicate tags to unique example to num tags?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. If adjacent or sibling `image` elements are in the input, what kind of output do you want to create?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing an example of the input, your current stylesheet and the expected output.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but you should change `<xsl:template match="@* | node()">` to`<xsl:template match="node()">`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have unique names for all the elements created from attributes, you could change:

```
<xsl:element name="{name()}">
```

to something like:

```
<xsl:element name="{name()}_{generate-id()}">
```

But this could make the result very difficult to process by the target application. A more reasonable approach might be:

```
<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="generate-id()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```